# Backbone with Oauth2 granttype password

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, oauth-2.0

I want to call an OAuth2 service with grant_type *password*.
I am using Backbone with Jquery.

Parameters for the POST:
grant_type=password
client_id=[YOUR_APP_ID]
client_secret=[YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET]
username=[USER_NAME]
password=[USER_PASSWORD]

I have tried several NPM plugins but all give error.

I have created a custom post AJAX but this also does not work:

```
       var results = $.ajax({

        // The URL to process the request
        url : "https://app1pub.smappee.net/dev/v1/oauth2/token",
        type : "POST",
        data : {
            grant_type : "password",//jshint ignore:line
            username: "myuser",
            password: "secret",
            client_id: "myclient",//jshint ignore:line
            client_secret: "clientSecret"//jshint ignore:line

        },
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $token");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        success: function(response) {
           //console.log(response);
           console.log(response.access_token);//jshint ignore:line
           data.access_token = response.access_token;//jshint ignore:line
           //tokenGranted();
        }

    });

    return results.responseText;
```

(see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gf70sss5/)

All give me the error:

```
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://app1pub.smappee.net/dev/v1/oauth2/token. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access."
```

Does anyone know a NPM plugin which works with the password granttype? Preferrably with an example. I have tried a few (like [simple-oauth2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-oauth2)) but I can't get any working.

Or an AJAX call which does work? Or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but i've still a problem with the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error

```
var url = 'https://app1pub.smappee.net/dev/v1/oauth2/token';

    // ajax call
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {"grant_type": "password", "client_id": client_id, "client_secret": client_secret,"username": username,"password": password},
        beforeSend : function(xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader("POST", "/dev/v1/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1");
          xhr.setRequestHeader("HOST", "app1pub.smappee.net");
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");

        },
        error : function() {
          // error handler
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // success handler
            alert(data["access_token"])
        }
```